# How to get a MySQL Value as a colour in EJS?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, ejs

I have a table in my nodeJS project that has data with a status. I would like to show this status in red and green. To render the HTML page I use EJS.

I've already tried using an if/else statement, but there I always get the first value of the statement.

MySQL:

```
SELECT g_id, g_name, g_status FROM games
```

EJS:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr class="table-info">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

        <% if (data) { 
            data.forEach(function(game){ 

            var status = game.g_status;

            if (status = '1') {
                status = 'color-green';
            } else {
                status = 'color-red';
            }
        %>
        <tbody id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td><%= game.g_name %></td>
                <td><%= status %></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <% }) %>
        <% } %>
</table>
```

What's the problem, and how do I get the SQL output to a specific colour?

Comment: shouldn't be     :  if (status == '1') {             ?

Comment: yes, that's right, i've probably overlooked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ternary condition like this way :

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr class="table-info">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

        <% if (data) { 
            data.forEach(function(game){ %>
            <tbody id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td><%= game.g_name %></td>
                <td><%= game.g_status=='1'?'color-green':'color-red' %></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        <% }) %>
        <% } %>
```

Comment: this works great, but how can I output both values as color?

Comment: it is depends on your requirements , when you want to show both colors

Comment: If the status in the DB is set to 1, these values ​​should be displayed in red if the value is 2 in green.

Comment: I just tried to do this via a JS variable, but there I do not get any HTML styles

Comment: inside your if condition try double = , ` if (status == '1') {`

Answer (score 0):

well. 
there is many places to look for.

1. read on equals operator in JavasScript
2. status is not part of the list, just app variable
3. create function returning color for given status